# Partition Hive based on the first chars of a field

Tags: database, hive

I am looking to store data into Hive to run analysis on the pas months (~100GB per days).

My rows contains a date (STRING) field looking like that: 2016-03-06T04:31:59.933012793+08:00

I want to partition based on this field but only based on the date (2016-03-06) --and i don't care about the timezone. Is there any ways to achieve that without changing the original format?

The reason for partitioning is both performances and the ability to delete old days to have a rolling window of data.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you storing the date as a string rather than a native data type?

Comment: Because of the time value, as far as I have seen there is no DATETIME field in hive.

Comment: True, you would normally use `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through Insert Overwrite table with dynamic partition.

You can apply sub-string or regexp_extract  function on your date time column and get the value in required format. 
Below is my sample query where I am loading a Partitioned table by applying function on the partition column.

```
CREATE TABLE base2(id int, name String)
PARTITIONED BY (state string);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE base2 PARTITION (state)
SELECT id, name, substring(state,0,1)
```

Here I am applying some transformation the partition column. Hope this helps.
    FROM base;